# Get data from an xml file

Tags: php, xml

In a php script how to read and convert a XML document to an object and access the obtained object in order to get his data?

```
<?php
$xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data request-id="ID">
<data name="Name1"
    d1="0"
    d2="0231234"
    d3="32584">
    <data name="Name2"
        d4="231234"
        d5="2012-06-06 18:18:10.000607"
        d6="3b048653-aaa9-485b-b0dd-d16e068230e9" />
    </data>
</data>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml); 
//how to get the data d1? or d4? from the obtained object
?>
```

Comment: You can try if this works:   $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml file');
  $deJson = json_encode($xml);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this function -

```
$xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data request-id="ID">
<data name="Name1"
    d1="0"
    d2="0231234"
    d3="32584">
    <data name="Name2"
        d4="231234"
        d5="2012-06-06 18:18:10.000607"
        d6="3b048653-aaa9-485b-b0dd-d16e068230e9" />
    </data>
</data>';
function xmlToArray($input, $callback = null, $recurse = false) {
                    $data = ((!$recurse) && is_string($input))? simplexml_load_string($input, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA): $input;
                    if ($data instanceof SimpleXMLElement) $data = (array) $data;
                    if (is_array($data)) foreach ($data as &$item) $item = xmlToArray($item, $callback, true);
                    return (!is_array($data) && is_callable($callback))? call_user_func($callback, $data): $data;
            }
$xml = xmlToArray($xml);
echo $xml['data']['@attributes']['d1'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $xml['data']['data']['@attributes']['d4'];
```

Comment: This is working but could you try to explain the logic of the function? I would like to mark this as accepted answer but I only think that there is a direct and simple method to get the data of an xml file.

Comment: Here, xmlToArray() is the function which parse your xml content and convert it into php array and you get the ouptup easily.

Comment: I know that this function convert the xml file to an array so it would be easier to get the data from an array element but I meant that why not using a defined function that convert the xml file into an object like simplexml_load_string() function

Comment: Yes, this is alternative to this function. Using simplexml_load_string(), you have to make object to get values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet:

```
<?php
$xmlstring = file_get_contents($filename);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$object = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$myxml = simplexml_load_string($xml); 
echo $myxml->data[1]['d1'];
echo $myxml->data[1]['d2'];
echo $myxml->data[1]['d3'];
echo $myxml->data[2]['d4'];
```

Reference : [How to parse XML with PHP5](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5)

Answer (score 0):

try :-

```
echo $xml['data']['@attributes']['d1'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $xml['data']['data']['@attributes']['d4'];
```